# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el tamaño completo de un canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");

function w() {return c.width;}

function h() {return c.height;}



var p = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(w(),h(),{view: c});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Intento devolver el `width` del `canvas 100%` pero me devuelve `100px`, porque necesito usarlo en pixijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [`element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

> devuelve el valor del atributo especificado en el elemento. Si el atributo especificado no existe, el valor retornado puede ser tanto null como "" (una cadena vacía)

Así por ejemplo:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");

function w() {
  console.log(c.getAttribute('width'));
  return c.getAttribute('width');
}

function h() {
  console.log(c.getAttribute('height'));
  return c.getAttribute('height');
}



var p = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(w(), h(), {
  view: c
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.5.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que los atributos `width` y `height` no aceptan unidades y siempre se consideran [pixeles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/canvas).

Para que el elemento canvas ocupe el ancho y el alto completo de la ventana con PixiJS, tedrás que pasarle sus valores:

```
var p = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
    window.innerWidth,     //ancho de la ventana
    window.innerHeight,    //alto de la ventana
    {view: c}
);
```